# Problem With Count()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I wants to write a query to retrieve `COUNT(of employees with the salary=1000)` and `COUNT(of total no of employees)` from the same table. 
any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
     count(*) totalCount, 
     count(case when salary = 1000 then 1 else NULL end) specialCount
from Employees
```

COUNT counts non-null rows.

Comment: this produces the same execution plan as the [answer from @Tom H.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207157/problem-with-count/3207303#3207303).  Also, you really don't need the `else NULL`, but removing it does not alter the execution plan.

Comment: @KM: Just putting it here as most of the people don't seem to know what COUNT actually counts:) Especially that count(*) equivalent to count(1), but not count(column) if column is nullable ...

Comment: +1, @ToxicAvenger, I agree, most don't understand COUNT.  your answer is just as fast as the [answer from @Tom H.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207157/problem-with-count/3207303#3207303) and much better than the ones with a subquery in the select list!

Answer (score 5):

Another method:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_employees,
    SUM(CASE WHEN salary = 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS employees_with_1000_salary
FROM
    Employees
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) as 'Total Employees',   
    (SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM Employees WHERE Salary = 1000) as 'Salaried'
    FROM Employees
```

Comment: Would you query the same table twice?

Comment: the use of a subquery in the select list is less efficient than single query like [@Tom H. answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207157/problem-with-count/3207303#3207303).  Using `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` this query TotalSubtreeCost almost 50% higher than the single query of @Tom H. answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as employeeCount,
(select count(*) from employee where salary=1000) as bigmoneyEmployeeCount
from employee
```